# Existence of limit of derivative implies uniformly continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (a, b] → R$ be continuous and such that $f'(x)$ exists on $(a, b)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f'(x)$ exists.

I know the existence of limit could imply uniform continuity. How can we prove that f is uniformly continuous on (a, b] when $f'(x)$ exist?

Comment: How does existence of the limit imply uniform continuity?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this mean that the function is only continuous on (a,b]?

Comment: The information about the uniformly continuity can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to a+} f'(x) = L$.  Given $\epsilon = 1$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f'(x) - L| < 1$ for all $x \in (a,\delta]$.  Hence, $f'$ is bounded on $(a,\delta]$ since, by the reverse triangle inequality,

$$|f'(x)| - |L| \leqslant |f'(x) - L| < 1 \implies |f'(x)| < |L| +1. $$

Since $f'$ is bounded on $(a,\delta]$ it follows by the mean value theorem that for all $x,y \in (a,\delta]$ there exists  $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$\tag{*}|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)(x-y)| = |f'(\xi)||x-y| \leqslant (|L| +1)|x-y|$$

I'll leave it to you to show easily that (*) implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,\delta]$.

Since $f$ is continuous and $[\delta,b]$ is a compact interval, it follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[\delta,b]$.

Finish by showing that uniform continuity on both $(a,\delta]$ and $[\delta,b]$ gives us uniform continuity on $(a,b] = (a,\delta] \cup [\delta,b]$.